# Fb share button not working

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to implement fb share button in my website and I followed the code provided by fb ('https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'). But clicking on button not opening fb share window.

Javascript code under script in html file:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
<script>  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId            : 'app-id',
  autoLogAppEvents : true,
  xfbml            : true,
  version          : 'v2.10'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

JS code in post.js file:

```
function fb_click(post_url, post_header) {
console.log(post_url);
console.log(post_header);
console.log('Facebook');

FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    mobile_iframe: true,
    href: post_url,
  }, function(response){});
```

}

1) Can someone help me what is the reason here?

2) How this FB variable make visible into post.js file.

Comment: what does the browser dev console say? any errors? do those console log entries get through?

Comment: Got error that FB is not defined in this post.js file.

Comment: you did not load the js sdk then. make sure it actually gets loaded (network tab), make sure not to try your code without any server. don´t just open the file in the browser without at least starting a server on localhost.